# Polyline simplification

Tags: javascript, gis, polyline

I am trying to understand [this](https://github.com/mourner/simplify-js/blob/master/simplify.js) code.

What I understand is that the code tries to refine the geometry based on a tolerance. Basically it checks if the distance between two points is less than the tolerance or not, and retains/removes the points accordingly.

I have a query though. Points are in lat-long format. The code simply calculates a square of the Euclidean distance(simple square formula we all know). Isn't this a wrong approach as lat-long based distance is different from Euclidean distance?

Second, what is the unit of tolerance? In this [test](https://github.com/mourner/simplify-js/blob/master/test/test.js), the tolerance value of 5 is used. How does this value fit in here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I understand is that code tries to refine the geometry based on tolerance. Basically it checks if distance between two points is less than tolerance or not, and retains/removes the points accrdingly.

Yes, that's a first step, in the second step it tries to find consecutive lines that are (basically) in line and merges them.

> I have a query though. Points are in lat-long format. Code simply calculates square of the Euclidean distance(simple square formula we all know). Isn't this a wrong approach as lat-long based distance are different from Euclidean distance?

```
(c) 2017, Vladimir Agafonkin
Simplify.js, a high-performance JS polyline simplification library
```

The code doesn't claim to be suitable for for lat-lng coordinates. Although they look like 2d-coordinates, they represent points in a 3d space; I don't see that the code was made for that.

On the other hand, it shouldn't be too complicated to rewrite it to 3d-space. And all you'd have to do then is to convert your lat-lng points into 3d-coordiantes

> Second, what is the unit of tolerance? In test, tolerance value of 5 is used. How does this value fit in here?

pixels, miles, doesn't matter. The same unit as the points that you pass.